# How to analyze the following complex number?

Tags: complex-numbers, fourier-series

$f(T) = \int_{0}^{1}e^{-iT\lambda(s)}ds$, where $\lambda(s)$ increases monotonously. I want to show that  $|f(T)|$ has an upper bound that decreases with $T$ for $T \gg 1$.

For example, if $\lambda(s) = s$ then $|f(T)| \le 2/T$.

This question comes from numerical analysis of my research. It's the expression of error analysis in adiabatic evolution. More specifically, the digital error has expression : $\sum_{k=1}^{L}e^{-iT\sum_{j<k}\lambda_{j}}/L$, where $\lambda_{j}$ equals $\lambda_{j} = \lambda(j/L)$. From numerical result I am sure it has an upper which bound decays with $T$. However, I don't know how to prove that. I wonder if there is related formulas in complex analysis and fourier series.

Comment: This is true if one adds some conditions on $\lambda$, for example that the derivative is separated from zero and increases. I will type the proof once they approve the problem. By the way, I have no idea why they closed it ... .

Comment: @Salcio Thank you! I think it’s true that the derivative of lambda is required to above zero. I open another question, you can find it in my page of the website. May I ask what kind of tool should be used?

Answer (score 1):

Remark: This answer was for the first version of the question which stated that $|f(T)|^2$ was monotonic.

The result is not true. If $\lambda(s) = s$, then
\begin{equation}
f(T) = \frac{1}{i T}(1 - e^{-i T})
\end{equation}
hence $f(2k\pi) = 0$ for $k\in {\mathbb{N}^*}$ but $f$ is not identically $0$, hence $|f(T)|^2$ is not monotonic.

Comment: Yes, but if you draw the figure of |f(T)| numerically, you can see it decrases with T as |1 - e^{-iT]| is constant. So is it possible to prove |f(T)| has an upper bound decreases with T?

Comment: I guess he wants f(T) to be bound from above by a function which decreases with T. In your case, $|f(T)| <= 2/T$

Answer (score 1):

I make here two assumptions on $\lambda$

1. it has derivative bounded from below by m > 0
2. derivative is monotonous (so $\frac{1}{\lambda^{'}}$ is also monotonous)

First off, if f(t) is a smooth function then $$f(s_{k}) - f(s_{k-1}) = f^{'}(s_{k-1})*(s_{k}-s_{k-1}) + \epsilon(s_{k}-s_{k-1})$$
This is just a mean value theorem.
Here $s_{1} < s_{2} < s_{3} <... <s_{n}$ is a partition of [0,1] and $\epsilon$ stands for something which tends to zero (uniformly) when $s_{k} - s_{k-1}$ tends to zero.
Using this for $f(s) = e^{iT\lambda(s)}$ one gets
$$e^{iT\lambda(s_{k})} - e^{iT\lambda(s_{k-1})}= iT\lambda^{'}(s_{k-1})e^{iT\lambda(s_{k-1})}(s_{k}-s_{k-1}) + \epsilon*(s_{k}-s_{k-1})$$
so
$$\frac{1}{iT\lambda^{'}(s_{k-1})}e^{iT\lambda(s_{k})} - e^{iT\lambda(s_{k-1})} = e^{iT\lambda(s_{k-1})}(s_{k}-s_{k-1}) + \frac{\epsilon*(s_{k}-s_{k-1})}{iT\lambda^{'}(s_{k-1})}$$
Now, writing the integral $\int_{0}^{1}e^{iT\lambda(s)}ds$ as the limit of Riemann' sums we have
$$\int_{0}^{1}e^{iT\lambda(s)}ds = \lim_{\Delta s \to 0}\sum_{k}(e^{iT\lambda(s_{k})} - e^{iT\lambda(s_{k-1})})(s_{k}-s_{k-1})$$
But from the formula above we see that the sum can be estimated by
$$\sum_{k}\frac{1}{iT\lambda^{'}(s_{k-1})}(e^{iT\lambda(s_{k})} - e^{iT\lambda(s_{k-1})}) - \sum_{k}\frac{\epsilon*(s_{k}-s_{k-1})}{iT\lambda^{'}(s_{k-1})}$$
The second sum is easy to bound from above (i.e. assuming that $\lambda^{'}$ is bound from below by, say m) we get
$$|\sum_{k}\frac{\epsilon*(s_{k}-s_{k-1})}{iT\lambda^{'}(s_{k-1})}| <= $$
$$\sum_{k}|\frac{\epsilon*(s_{k}-s_{k-1})}{iT\lambda^{'}(s_{k-1})}| <= $$
$$\frac{1}{Tm}\sum_{k}|\epsilon*(s_{k}-s_{k-1})| <=$$
$$\frac{max(\epsilon)}{Tm}\sum_{k}|(s_{k}-s_{k-1})| <=$$
$$\frac{max(\epsilon)}{Tm}$$
Now we have to estimate the first sum
$$\frac{1}{iT}\sum_{k}\frac{1}{\lambda^{'}(s_{k-1})}(e^{iT\lambda(s_{k})} - e^{iT\lambda(s_{k-1})}) $$
When we change order of summation we get that the sum is
$$|\frac{1}{iT}\sum_{k}\frac{1}{\lambda^{'}(s_{k-1})}(e^{iT\lambda(s_{k})} - e^{iT\lambda(s_{k-1})}) | <= $$
$$|\frac{1}{iT}\sum_{k}(\frac{1}{\lambda^{'}(s_{k})} - \frac{1}{\lambda^{'}(s_{k-1})}) e^{iT\lambda(s_{k-1}}) | + 2\frac{1}{Tm} <= $$
$$\frac{1}{T}\sum_{k}|(\frac{1}{\lambda^{'}(s_{k})} - \frac{1}{\lambda^{'}(s_{k-1})}) e^{iT\lambda(s_{k-1}}) | + 2\frac{1}{Tm} <= $$
$$\frac{1}{T}\sum_{k}|(\frac{1}{\lambda^{'}(s_{k})} - \frac{1}{\lambda^{'}(s_{k-1})}) | + 2\frac{1}{Tm} <= $$
And since $\frac{1}{\lambda^{'}}$ is by assumption monotone we can skip absolute values under the last sum to get
$$\frac{1}{T}|\frac{1}{\lambda^{'}(0)} - \frac{1}{\lambda^{'}(1)} | + 2\frac{1}{Tm} $$

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, sir. But I notice that in the proof it's implied that L (up range of k) is much larger than T, while in numerical it happens that the 1/T scaling is still true when T is larger than L. Do you know what might cause this situation?

Comment: Sure, L is the limit in Riemann sum so it is large (goes to infinity). T is arbitrary but fixed. In words, first we take T (now it is fixed) and then take large L. As large as needed.

Comment: No I mean numerically the scaling of O(1/T) is more "stable" than expected. For example, one can set L = 2000, and $\lambda(s) = 1$. If we sum $\sum_{k=1}^{L}e^{iT}/L$, the norm of final result is |e^{i(L+1)T/L}-1|/L|e^{iT/L}-1|, which has upper bound 4/T when $\sin(T/2L) > T/4L$. And this upper bound is approximately true even when T>L. If $\lambda(s)$ is a function similar to a constant, the above phenomenon also appears.

Comment: Sorry I meant $\lambda(s) = s$, the summation is $\sum_{k=1}^{L}e^{ikT/L}/L$.

Comment: I am sure it is correct, I mean that the order of the integral is 1/T (times some constants). Of course, under assumptions that $\lambda^{'}$ is bounded from zero and monotone. In the case above, the sum adds up to something like $ 2/|1-e^{iT/L}| * 1/L$  and for large L it should be around 1/T.

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to prove that $f(T)$ tends to $0$ when $T$ tends to infinity, because this is equivalent to having an upper bound that decreases to $0$, namely $U(T) = \sup_{T'\ge T}|f(T')|$.

Let us suppose that $\lambda(s)$ is differentiable and that $\lambda'(s)$ never vanishes. The substitution $x = \lambda(s)$ gives
\begin{equation}
f(T) = \int_{\lambda^{-1}([0,1])}e^{-iTx}\frac{1}{|\lambda'(\lambda^{-1}(x))|} d x
\end{equation}
The [Riemann-Lebesgue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma) lemma now tells us that $\lim_{T\to\infty}f(T) = 0$ because $\chi_{x\in\lambda^{-1}([0,1])} \frac{1}{|\lambda'(\lambda^{-1}(x))|}\in L^1({\mathbb R})$. Indeed, its integral is $f(0) = 1$.

I'm pretty confident the differentiability assumption can be replaced by a weaker condition with some work.