# How to upper bound the norm the following quantity?

Tags: complex-analysis, upper-lower-bounds

$f(T) = \int_{0}^{1}e^{-iT\lambda(s)}ds$, where $\lambda(s)$ increases monotonously. I want to prove it satisfies $|f(T)|^{2}$ has a proper upper bound that decreases with $T$ for $T \gg 1$.

For example, $\lambda(s) = s$ then $|f(T)| \le 2/T$.

This question comes from numerical analysis of my research. It's the expression of error analysis in adiabatic evolution. More specifically, the digital error has expression : $\sum_{k=1}^{L}e^{-iT\sum_{j<k}\lambda_{j}}/L$, where $\lambda_{j}$ equals $\lambda_{j} = \lambda(j/L)$. From numerical result I am sure it has an upper bound decays with $T$. However, I don't know how to prove that. I wonder if there is related formulas in complex analysis and fourier series.

Comment: Sir you should not ask the same question again

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to analyze the following complex number?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3971687/how-to-analyze-the-following-complex-number)

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi It was closed.